# xcode ios project taking long time to compile and run?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, sup

My application is taking very long time around 10 minutes to compile and run on simulator. The application was running fine initially however after adding SUP static library it is taking very long time to build.

xcode version:4.6

I have tried resetting the simulator and restarting the machine

Please help.

Comment: There are some ideas to try:
- remove build files from organizer
- try to use CocoaPods and/or workspace - it gives faster compilation

Try to find what is taking time, is it compilation or linking time?

Comment: CLEAN the project rebuild and run again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I answered to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479085/how-to-decrease-build-times-speed-up-compile-time-in-xcode), I wrote an extensive blog post about how I improved iOS development cycle at Spotify:

[Shaving off 50% waiting time from the iOS Edit-Build-Test cycle](https://engineering.atspotify.com/shaving-off-time-from-the-ios-edit-build-test-cycle/)

It boiled down to:

1) Stop generating dSYM bundles.

2) Avoid compiling with -O4 if using Clang.

Comment: Fixed link but the images are broken in your post