# Project-Swift.h file after Swift 3.0 migration is compiling the same functions hundreds of times and taking 7 minutes to compile

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

After migrating to Swift 3.0 our first time build time now takes 7 minutes when it used to take 1:20. Does anyone know how can I speed this up?

I work on a large project with lots of Objective C files, approximately 640 Swift files, 20 Cocoapod dependencies, a Today View extension and UITests. After the first time build, an incremental build only takes about 10 seconds.

I have run the excellent Build Time Analyzer here: 
https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode
 and attached a screenshot below.

[image]

It seems that several of the functions in about 20 of the classes are compiled 631 times. This seems like the problem but I don't know how to fix it. No other function or class takes very long to compile on its own.

Almost all of the 7 minute build time is spent on compiling swift files up until this output:
[image]
After this line all of the rest of the swift files are compiled and run in about 10 seconds.

It's worth noting that the generated project-swift.h file is 4500 lines long and the bridging-header has 150 lines of imports.

Comment: Have you tried deleting derived data?

Comment: @dylanthelion Yes.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I was fortunate in that the file responsible for this was no longer used in the project. So, I could afford to delete it

Comment: I would just like to point out that the column to the left of the Build Time Analyzer is cumulative build time. Rather than 631 * 65.6 ms, the math is already done for you and is 65.6 ms in total.

Comment: @Robert I don't believe that is true. It should work that way but it doesn't. If it was cumulative time then it would mean that file is being compiled in .103 milliseconds (65.6 / 631). I wish the Swift compiler was that fast!

Comment: @RobertWagstaff - No, the cumulative time is 65.6ms. Not .103ms and not 38.74s. It's not the file that compiles in .1 ms but the individual routine. If you look in the log files, you'll find that some routines compiles even quicker than 0.1 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fix! Turned out to be just a settings change as detailed in this SO post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370475/1455770

[image]

This change got my compile down from 7 minutes to a far more manageable 2 minutes. Build Time Analyzer shows each file compiling only once now. I'm not 100% sure why this fixed the problem but I noticed that while generating the module-swift.h file the compiler now seems to generate it all in one go instead of file by file. This turns out to be a lot faster.

Comment: Oh good. Please remember to tick this as the correct answer, as it is

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete solution, but here is at least what is happening. So, you might have 631 files pointing to `ViewControllerRecycler.swift`.

lets say that ClassA calls something from `ViewControllerRecycler.swift`, ClassC calls something from `ViewControllerRecycler.swift` and so on.

If you follow [this](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-dev/Week-of-Mon-20160411/001693.html) and add the debugging flag `-driver-show incremental` to "other swift flags", you will see something like:

```
Queuing ViewControllerRecycler.swift
Queuing ClassA.swift
Queuing ViewControllerRecycler.swift because of dependencies discovered later
```

and then

```
Queuing ViewControllerRecycler.swift because of dependencies discovered later
Queuing ViewControllerRecycler.swift because of dependencies discovered later
Queuing ViewControllerRecycler.swift because of dependencies discovered later
```

something like that. When ClassA is changed, for example, even if it is nothing about ViewControllerRecycler.swift, it will be queued for compilation again "due to dependencies". This causes your files to be compiled so many times.

You may want to look at the following sites to try to optimise your code to be more faster:

- https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/26/swift-long-compile-time/
- [XCode 8 very slow swift compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879979/xcode-8-very-slow-swift-compiling)
- [Xcode 8 does full project rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456223/xcode-8-does-full-project-rebuild)
- http://bits.citrusbyte.com/improving-swift-compile-time/
- https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/regarding-swift-build-time-optimizations-fc92cdd91e31#.8pvjh9p27

Maybe these will help you to compile a bit, if not extremely, faster